# datatables updating row sets on the fly post instantiation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So, I have a table that updates at regular intervals using a heartbeat method, of which I have no problem updating data visually within the given columns of any given row as the need requires. However the data for the API to use for sorting, and all that datatables does in the background is lost, as my method doesn't use the API respectively.

It just finds a class that I gave the row `tr` itself then finds `td` within matching the column(s) I need to update at the time.

So I am trying to figure out how to update any given row and any given column(s) within that row on the fly. Or is there a way to get datatables to refresh what it knows, without having to reload the page or destroy the table, to completely redraw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fnUpdate` from the [API](http://datatables.net/api) in your "heartbeat method".

It has flexible parameters that let you update any row/column/cell on the fly.

I've created a little demo [here](http://live.datatables.net/eserop/edit#javascript,html,live) that updates 1st row upon a button click.

Comment: I inadvertantly came to this same conclusion after continuing to dig around, and try different methods. For me, disabling the pre/post draw, and updating a full row rather than a column on a single row when going over multiple rows worked out perefectly. But your demonstration is fairly spot on for the overall need as well so, Thank you. :-_)